# How to find songs on iPod

Tags: itunes, ipod

I recently downloaded a YouTube playlist, ripped the audio, and added it to my iPod/iTunes library. Currently the songs are in my "Recently Added" playlist, but once they disappear from there, I don't know I'll find them.

I've checked if the name of the playlist (also the name of the directory the files are stored in) is being used as either the album name or artist name, and it's not.

Answer (score 3):

Choose the track in iTunes and choose get info (cmd-I)

The summary tab gives a description of the track including album, artist etc and the full path in the filesystem

The info tab gives the details of the album, artist, album artist ie what artist appears in the iTunes listing

The sorting tab might also be of interest for this issue

These artist and albums will also be the ones used on the iPod

Also you can change the recently added playlist to include more tracks by changing the number in the definition of the smart playlist

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a Smart Playlist called “Recently Added” (or similar) with the following rules (adjust to your likings):

[image: Smart Playlist]

**note**: the “media is not podcast” is my own thing, you can remove that, but it’s pretty straightforward.

Comment: He already has that playlist (apple sets it up in the install

Comment: The he should start using it ;)